# Ошибка рассылки VkBottle Python

Tags: python

Не получается сделать массовую рассылку юзеров из группы вк. При попытке отправить рассылку, вылезает ошибка:

```
"TypeError: 'usrget' is an invalid keyword argument for int()"
```

проблемный кусочек кода:

```
@bot.on.private_message(text='Сделать рассылку')
async def rass(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Какую рассылку будем делать?')
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.peer_id, FormState.RASSILKA)
 
@bot.on.private_message(text='<rp>', state=FormState.RASSILKA)
async def handler(message:Message, rp):
    usrget = await bot.api.groups.get_members(group_id=секрет, offset=100, count=500)
    await bot.api.messages.send(usrget, rp)
```

памагите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, в Вашей переменной `usrget` находится массив из пользователей, а метод `bot.api.messages.send()` отправляет сообщение одному пользователю.

Попробуйте так:

```py
@bot.on.private_message(text='<rp>', state=FormState.RASSILKA)
async def handler(message:Message, rp):
    usrget = await bot.api.groups.get_members(group_id=секрет, offset=100, count=500)
    for user_id in usrget:
        await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=user_id, message=rp, random_id=0)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но есть еще одна проблема, которая последовала после решения этой ошибки.
Теперь выдается ошибка - ( abc.CodeErrorFactory_100: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: random_id not integer )

Если не сложно, подскажите, что в таком случае можно сделать? Спасибо

Comment: Это в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: await bot.api.messages.send(user_id, rp)

Comment: Посмотрите, что находится в переменной user_id:
`print(user_id)`

Comment: там айдишники юзеров выдает

Comment: Исправил, сейчас должно работать, проверьте

Comment: все работает. спасибо